# WPF RichTextBox text from bottom

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I'm trying to make a chat window, like IRC, in which the contents are shown from bottom to top, just like any chat window ever created.

This is my xaml, nothing fancy about it

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ee="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/effects" xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing" x:Class="TestChat.Chat"
    Title="Chat" Height="700" Width="400" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">

    <Grid>
        <RichTextBox x:Name="txtChat" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="644" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="388" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <FlowDocument />
        </RichTextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And i have a backgroundworker adding text to it

```
private void SendWorkerComplete(object s, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
{
    txtChat.AppendText(args.UserState.ToString());
    txtChat.ScrollToEnd();
}

private void SendWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    SendWorker.ReportProgress(0, (string)e.Argument);
}
```

The VerticalContentAlignment property set to bottom does not render the contents this way, how could this be done? is there a property for it or it has to be done programmatically?

Comment: Here is a similar requirement. Not exactly as you have specified, but it may work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308475/how-can-i-make-a-richtextbox-scroll-to-the-end-when-i-add-a-new-line

Comment: That only scrolls to the bottom but if the richtextbox is empty there's no use to reproduce this behaviour, i guess i could add a bunch of empty lines and scrolling to end before appending the output to it to reproduce this, but i was looking for a more elegant way to do it, thanks anyway

Comment: Could you show us the xaml you're using?

Comment: Sure, there's nothing remarkable about it though

Comment: Is there any reason you need a RichTextBox? See my answer.

Comment: I've used approximately 10 different IRC and IM clients both web pages and installed software and I can't think of any of them that showed messages at the bottom **with empty space above**. They all simply added each message as it came in and after the window was filled from the top down it auto scrolled the window so that the latest message was always visible.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/6192255/934912

Comment: @StillLearnin will do in a couple hours, but your comment on your solution made more sense to me, it doesn't answer the question directly but i think is the way to go in my case, thanks a lot. And to answer your previous comment, good old mIRC starts with the text at the bottom

Comment: Ha! That's an IRC client that I've looked at but never used. I guess I'm

Comment: Hahahaha, by the way, please edit your answer to add your comment to it so i can accept it, and the only workaround i could find about the other issue was adding empty lines for the cursor to reach the bottom of the rtb. I don't want to answer my own question as your solution lead me to the right way of doing this, so please edit yours with all this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with a RichTextBox? Just use a regular TextBox.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtChat" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="10" Text="Hello" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: It is a chat, so it needs to have emoticons, different fonts sizes, styles, colors... you get the idea

Comment: @FuuRe Ah! I see. I assumed that you were going with just a plain text interface because if I were doing it, and wanted to handle emoticons fancy styling etc, I definitely wouldn't use a richtextbox. I'd first of all build a message class with all its associated properties (sender, message, etc) and then build a custom xaml control to represent the message object. Each time a message arrives, create a new message object and add it to a collection. Bind a listview to that collection with the list item template being your custom xaml control.

Answer (score -1):

you've set margin-left to 545 that goes rich text box out of Window changing your code to something like this shows your control on bottom of window:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="txtChat" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="42" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="Yellow">
        <FlowDocument />
</RichTextBox>
```